# change my upload system with c#

Tags: c#

i want to make my code could be upload in .docx or .pdf
im so confuse, how can i change my code to that ?
im just can upload when my data is image

there is my code in aspx.cs

```
protected void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //upload photo
    int h, w; string Folder = "photo/";
    h = 298; w = 765;
    string asl = uploadIncResize(h, w, Folder, upload, false);
    string insert = "insert into PM_formKL(title, proponent, assessor, score, upload) "
                    + "values('" + Cf.StrSql(title.Text) + "','" + Cf.StrSql(proponent.Text) + "','" + Cf.StrSql(assessor.Text) + "','" + Cf.StrSql(score.Text) + "','" + asl + "')";
    Db.Execute(insert);

    Response.Redirect("/detail penilaian/KL/formkl.aspx");
}

// SO upload image
protected string uploadFile(string Folder, FileUpload img)
{
    string upload_file = "";
    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(img.FileName);
        string dir = Param.PathImage + Folder;
        bool status = true;

        while (status)
        {
            status = FileExists(filename, Server.MapPath("~/images/" + Folder));
            if (status)
                filename = getRandomFileName() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(img.PostedFile.FileName);
        }

        //teaser_image.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + Folder + filename);
        upload_file = filename;
        string large = dir + filename;

        img.PostedFile.SaveAs(large);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Js.Alert(this, "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message);
    }
    return upload_file;
}

protected string uploadIncResize(int h, int w, string Folder, FileUpload img, bool resize)
{
    string upload_file = "";
    try
    {
        if (img.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || img.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png" || img.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/gif")
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(img.FileName);
            string dir = Param.PathImage + Folder;
            bool status = true;

            while (status)
            {
                status = FileExists(filename, Server.MapPath("~/images/" + Folder));
                if (status)
                    filename = getRandomFileName() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(img.PostedFile.FileName);
            }

            upload_file = filename;

            string temp = dir + "(kl)" + filename;
            string large = dir + filename;

            img.PostedFile.SaveAs(temp);
            if (resize)
            {
                Imgh.Crop(temp, large, h, w);
            }
            else
            {
                img.PostedFile.SaveAs(large);
            }
            File.Delete(temp);
            Js.Alert(this, "Upload status: upload successfull.");
        }
        else
            Js.Alert(this, "Upload status: Only JPEG , PNG or GIF files are allowed!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Js.Alert(this, "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message);
    }
    return upload_file;
}

protected string getRandomFileName()
{
    Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    int newFile = 0;
    newFile = rand.Next(1, 9999999);

    return newFile.ToString();
}

protected bool FileExists(string filename, string path)
{
    FileInfo imageFile = new FileInfo(path + filename);
    bool fileStatus = imageFile.Exists;
    return fileStatus;
}
```

Comment: Use the `uploadFile` method, not the the `uploadIncResize`one. That one for images only

Comment: Side note: Please read up on using parameters with whatever database layer you're using (they're almost certainly an option because no sane database layer in the last 10 years hasn't let you add parameters) rather than what looks like some hokey attempt to fix strings as they're mangled into the query.

Comment: ok, i already solve my proble, thanks